# Mapping functions to reduce Time Complexity? PhD Qual Item

Tags: algorithm

This was on my last comp stat qual.  I gave an answer I thought was pretty good.  We just get our score on the exam, not whether we got specific questions right.  Hoping the community can give guidance on this one, I am not interested in the answer so much as what is being tested and where I can go read more about it and get some practice before the next exam.

At first glance it looks like a time complexity question, but when it starts talking about mapping-functions and pre-sorting data, I am not sure how to handle.
So how would you answer?

Here it is:

> Given a set of items X = {x1, x2, ..., xn} drawn from some domain Z, your task is to find if a query item q in Z occurs in the set.  For simplicity you may assume each item occurs exactly once in X and that it takes O(l) amount of time to compare any two items in Z.
>
> (a) Write pseudo-code for an algorithm which checks if q in X. What is the worst case time complexity of your algorithm?
>
> (b) If l is very large (e.g. if each element of X is a long video) then one needs efficient algorithms to check if q \in X.  Suppose you are given access to k functions h_i: Z -> {1, 2, ..., m} which uniformly map an element of Z to a number between 1 and m, and let k << l and m > n.
> Write pseudo-code for an algorithm which uses the function h_1...h_k to check if q \in X. Note that you are allowed to preprocess the data.  What is the worst case time complexity of your algorithm?
>
> Be explicit about the inputs, outputs, and assumptions in your pseudocode.

Comment: What is the nature of X? Is it a list, an array? How do you access elements and what is the time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

The first seems to be a simple **linear scan**. The time complexity is `O(n * l)`, the worst case is to compare all elements. Note - it cannot be sub-linear with `n`, since there is no information if the data is sorted.

The second (b) is actually a variation of **[bloom-filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)**, which is a probabalistic way to represent a set. Using bloom filters - you might have false positives (say something is in the set while it is not), but never false negative (say something is not int the set, while it is).